# Decide on var type based on input string

Tags: java, arrays, types

Say we have an array named `L` and an input string `in`.
 If `in` has a form like this `[0,1,2,3]`, L should be an `int[]` containing the numbers 0, 1, 2 and 3, but if `in` is like this `<0,1,2>`, then `L` should be a `String[]` containing the Strings "0", "1" and "2". 
Is this possible to do in Java? Or is there a way to define an array that accepts whatever type you put into it and then behaves like an array of that type?


I've thought about why I need this and came to the conclusion that I can kind of work around it. It requires some manual writing in the actual code, which means that it'll never be a compilable program, but unless a solution is found, I'll just use this dirty solution. Thank you for your answers! 
 
EDIT: It seems like this problem is impossible to solve the way I want it with natural Java. I'll use the dirty solution as described above. Once again, thank you anyways. Also that strange edit was me, I didn't realize I wasn't logged in.

Comment: The closest thing I can suggest is an `Object[]`.

Comment: It's actually Object, since an int[] is not an Object[]. Unless you store Integers, and not ints.

Comment: Why do you need / want to do this? [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) array because [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) and [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) are [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html):

```
           java.lang.Object
                  |
       +----------+----------+  
       |                     |
       v                     |
java.lang.Number             |
       |                     |
       v                     v
java.lang.Integer    java.lang.String
```

---

Exemple:

```
Object[] array = new Object[] {
    0,          //integer value
    "hello",    //String value
}
```

or

```
Object[] array = new Object[2];
array[0] = 0;          //integer value
array[1] = "hello";    //String value
```

Comment: `Object[] L = {0,1}; System.out.println(L[1]-L[0]);` This won't work, but I need it to work.

Comment: To use the array elements as integers, you have to cast them to integers: `Object[] L = {0,1}; System.out.println((int) L[1] - (int) L[0]);`

Answer (score 1):

As Joe C suggested, you can store it as an Object[].

And when you need to utilize it, you can cast the whole Object[] into a int[] or String[] using code like this:

```
Integer[] integerArray = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length, Integer[].class);
int[] intArray = Arrays.stream(integerArray).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

or

```
String[] stringArray = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length, String[].class);
```

Comment: If the underlying array the `Object[]` variable is a reference to is actually of type `String[]` or `Integer[]` (e.g. `Object[] a = new String[5]`), you can (and should) just cast it instead of using `copyOf`.

Comment: After reading it again, the user's getting this in the form of a `in` string. Which like you mentioned, begs the XY question. If it's coming in as a String in the first place, why would you need to make it an Object at the start.

Answer (score 0):

If there are always two type of String, then

```
String s = "<1,2,4>";
Object[] oArr;
if (s.contains("["))
{  
    //extract the string between the bracket
    s = s.substring(s.indexOf("[") + 1);
    s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("]"));
    // split by comma, which return String array and convert to Integer[]
    oArr = Arrays.stream(s.split(",")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);

}
else
{ 
    //extract the string between the bracket
    s = s.substring(s.indexOf("<") + 1);
    s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(">"));
    // split by comma, which return String array  
    oArr = s.split(",");
}
```

Comment: This produces either an array called iArr or one called sArr. I need both var names to be the the same.

Comment: @mindoverflow JBNizet already mentioned that's not possible until we store them into `Object[]`. If you are thinking about object array then, it can't be `int[]` instead `Integer[]`. Are you fine with then ?

Comment: @mindoverflow I have updated my posted as you asked.